# How to implement an "OR" condition on two strings with Result Validation in F#?

Tags: f#

I am attempting to implement an "or" condition in validating strings. I am failing miserably.

Given the following in F#:

```
let isSearchLastName  input = let (fn:string,ln:string) = input
                              if String.IsNullOrEmpty(ln.Trim()) then Error input else Ok input

let isSearchFirstName input = let (fn:string,ln:string) = input
                              if String.IsNullOrEmpty(fn.Trim()) then Error input else Ok input

let validatenamesearch = isSearchLastName ||| isSearchFirstName
                                

let isSearchNameValid = validatenamesearch  (m.SearchLastName, m.SearchFirstName) |> Result.Ok
```

Where, ||| is:

```
let oorr addSuccess addFailure switch1 switch2 x =
    match (switch1 x),(switch2 x) with
    | Ok s1,Ok s2 -> Ok (addSuccess s1 s2)
    | Error f1,Ok s2  -> Ok (addSuccess f1 s2)
    | Ok s1 ,Error f2 -> Ok (addSuccess s1 f2)
    | Error f1,Error f2 -> Error (addFailure f1 f2)
   
// create a "or" function for validation functions
let (|||) v1 v2 =
    let addSuccess r1 r2 = r1,r2 
    let addFailure s1 s2 = s1,s2
    oorr addSuccess addFailure v1 v2
```

I am attempting to use the above something like:

if isSearchNameValid then ......

What I am getting is the compiler complaining with:

```
val isSearchNameValid: Result<Result<((string*string)*(string*string)),((string*string)*(string*string))>,obj>
```

What I am hoping to achieve is a validation method where should either string be non-empty, the result will be success (with Ok) and I can then use the returned values from the Ok. (or if fails --i.e., neither string is non-empty--then abort further processing). Eventually, I would like to be able to chain together multiple "OR" conditions using the ||| operator.

Any help is most appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```ml
let (|||) op1 op2 arg =
    match op1 arg with
        | Ok value -> Ok value
        | Error _ -> op2 arg

let isSearchNameValid =
    isSearchLastName ||| isSearchFirstName
```

Example:

```ml
let john = "John", "Lennon"
isSearchNameValid john |> printfn "%A"   // Ok ("John", "Lennon")

let paul = "Paul", ""
isSearchNameValid paul |> printfn "%A"   // Ok ("Paul", "")

let blank = "", ""
isSearchNameValid blank |> printfn "%A"  // Error ("", "")
```